# addClass jquery loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on a web project that has a changing background image every few seconds. Problem is I don't know how to get the first image to return after all images are finished rotating. After the third image the screen goes white.

html :

```
<section class="slideshow">
    <img src="img/img1.png" class="bgM show"/>
    <img src="img/img2.png" class="bgM"/>
    <img src="img/img3.jpg" class="bgM"/>                   
</section>
```

javascript

```
function switch() {
    var $active = $('.slideshow IMG.show');
    var $next = $active.next(); 
    var $images = new Array(); 
    var $length = $images.length;

    $next.addClass('show');

    $active.removeClass('show');

    if ($images[$length].hasClass('show')) {
        $images[0].addClass('show');
    }
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "switch()", 8000 );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/kst4u4je/)***

No need for the extra code. Just use an iterator with mod for the set of image elements.

```js
$(function() {
 var slide = $(".slideshow"), cur = 0;
 setInterval(function(){
  $('.show',slide).removeClass('show');
  $('img',slide).eq((++cur)%3).addClass('show');
 }, 1000 );//using 1000 just for demo purposes
});
```

```css
.slideshow img.show{
    border:2px solid red;
    display:block;
}
.slideshow img{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="slideshow">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="bgM show"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" class="bgM"/>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="bgM"/>                   
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks all useful suggestions, this answer worked well for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

The first major issue is that your function `switch` is a reserved word (ie choose another name [I chose switch_images]).

Next you can check to see if the "next" image exists (`.length`). If it doesn't then set it to the first image in the slideshow:

```
<section class="slideshow">
    <img src="img/img1.png" class="bgM show"/>
    <img src="img/img2.png" class="bgM"/>
    <img src="img/img3.jpg" class="bgM"/>                   
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function switch_images() {
    var $active = $('.slideshow IMG.show');
    var $next = $active.next();

    if(!$next.length){
        $next = $('.slideshow IMG:first');
    }

    $active.removeClass('show');
    $next.addClass('show');
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "switch_images()", 8000 );
});
</script>
```